# Change li order with change of resolution

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an ul, which works like columns for fluidity reasons. Is there a way to put last li in first place, when screen resolution changes?

**Edit:**
Ok. Trying to make it work with flex box.

```
 .postpreview ul {
list-style: none;
display: inline-flex;

}

.postpreview ul li {
flex: 0 100px 30px;
}

@media(max-width: 1000px) {
postpreview ul {
flex-direction: row-reverse;
justify-content: flex-end;
 }
}
```

Now, when resolution changes to mobile, it stays on the right, and I, actually need it to be at the top.
Live link here
http://soloveich.com/pr6/blog/

Comment: posible with jquery ui and jquery.

Comment: You want to reverse li order based on screen size?

Comment: Possible with flex-box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS-only solution using [flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes):

```
ul {
  display: flex;
}
li {
  flex: 0 0 30px;
}
@media(max-width: 1000px) {
  ul {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ceso), screen width threshold is at 1000px.

**Update**: if you need to change layout from horizontal to vertical, use `flex-direction: column` in media query. Having examples of what and when you want to have would help, the question could use some clarification.

Comment: Took a better look. Flex boxes look awesome! Gotta redo the html a little bit. I guess I'll open a new question when something specific comes up. Thank you for pointing in that direction!

Answer (score 0):

css code:

```
nav ul li { display: inline; margin: 0 100px; }
```

html code:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

JS Code:

```
function Func(){
var list = $('nav ul li'),
    firstLi = list.first().offset().top,
    lastLi = list.last().offset().top,
    mLeft = parseInt(list.css('marginLeft')),
    mRight = parseInt(list.css('marginRight'))
if(firstLi != lastLi){
    --mLeft
    --mRight
    list.css({
        'marginLeft': mLeft,
        'marginRight': mRight
     })  
     Func();
  }
}

 Func();
```

**one other solution  :**

you can use media queries for different resolutions.

Comment: http://vanilla-js.com

Comment: I know i can change styling with media queries, but is there really a way to change order. The thing is, in first li, i have blog content, and in second one, i have date and comments info. So when resolution changes to mobile, date and comments end up on the bottom. I need them on the top, while keeping on the right with larger resolution.

Comment: yes you can do this with help of media queries and jQuery. like run jquery on various resolution.

Answer (score 0):

```
var litag = $('ul');
var litags = litag.children('li');
litag.append(litags.get().reverse());
```